# Redirecting Controller through OWIN startup

Tags: asp.net-core, owin

I am not a .net developer and got a task to apply SSO in an existing .net application. 
I have added OWIN OpenIDConnect for SSO. My project is not MVC project. Now my call is going through Startup.cs at the iisexpress server startup time. But my login page (login.aspx) is being called with /login.aspx.
I want to call startup when I call submit button on login page. The call is not going through startup.
My ConfigureAuth method is

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/login.ashx")
    });
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = "Authority",
            ClientId = "ClientId",
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
            ClientSecret = "ClientSecret",
            Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
            ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
            {
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
                {
                    //I'm able to break into this method
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                MessageReceived = (context) =>
                {
                    //doesn't seem to run this line
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                SecurityTokenReceived = (context) =>
                {
                    //doesn't seem to run this line
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                SecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
                {
                    //doesn't seem to run this line
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                {
                    //doesn't seem to run this line
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                {
                    //doesn't seem to run this line
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
            }
         });

    System.Console.WriteLine("After OpenIdconfiguration");
}
```

Please suggest how can I redirect the Controller call through startup class.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that most of the code will not be executed directly.  These are events that are executed as part of the authentication process.

The longer answer is that you need to fill in the blanks on what needs to actually happen for each of these events.  A little bit of information on OWIN might help.

I think of OWIN as a pipeline that leads to your application.  The request goes through the pipeline before it reaches your application.  When your application sends a response, this pipeline is used again.  Along the way, there are components called "middleware" that can act on the request and on the response.  Using the pipeline model, think of the middleware as valves in the pipeline.  The middleware is executed in order on the way in, and in reverse order on the way out.

So back to your code.  This line:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
```

Tells OWIN to use OpenIdConnect for authentication.  You need to write the code for each of the events that are part of the OpenIdConnect process.  The first one `RedirectToIdentityProvider` needs to redirect (probably with an http 302) to your identity provider, which could be something like ForgeRock or PingIdentity or IdentityServer.  Each of those events needs the code written for them.

The whole topic of OpenIdConnect is a fairly broad and is more than a little complex, probably more than what I could realistically do inside an answer.  But there are plenty of resources on the topic.

I hope that helps